# Deploying an excel add-in without signing the referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How can I deploy an excel add-in without actually signing all the referenced assemblies that the project has? I'm doing something for internal company use and I don't want to sign them. I'm using VSTO and Visual studio 2013. Deployment is done through Click Once.

I'm getting the following error on some computers:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx).

Take a look at the [Troubleshooting common VSTO issues – Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2012/10/08/troubleshooting-common-vsto-issues-part-2.aspx) page for possible solutions.

Comment: This requires me to sign the assembly.

Comment: Are you talking about the strong names? What is the problem to sign assemblies with an .snk file?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to add the source site in trusted sites on user's machines.

1. Open Control Panel-->Internet Options
2. Navigate to Security Tab
3. Click on Trusted Sites and open Sites
4. Add the source site as trusted.